# Make a table with an attribute of another table. Sap Hybris

Tags: java, attributes, sap-commerce-cloud, modeling

I have a question regarding modeling in Hybris.
For example, I have two different tables with next fields:

Table1:

- attribute1;

Table2:

- attribute2;

Can I create a new table with some attribute ("attributeName") that will link to one or another field from Table1 or Table2 at the same time? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Maybe you can use dynamic attribute.

Comment: if you are trying to link or do any operation then dynamic attribute is best way, otherwise composite reference you can use I guess.